# how to implement ANS X9.24 dukpt using java

Tags: java

Can anyone please help me with an example of source code which implements the processing algorithm for generating PIN using DUKPT?The code could be in Java or any other language.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how DUKPT works, but using the excellent [Thales Simulator Project](http://thalessim.codeplex.com/), I took the DUKPT code and ported it to a Java library, my very own [crypto-utils](https://bitbucket.org/joxley/crypto-utils/overview) project.

**Disclaimer:**  This was a learning exercise for myself and is ***NOT*** production code.  It may be of help

Answer (score 2):

I found this c# project immensely helpful, and easy to understand - should help you no matter what language you ultimately need it in.

https://github.com/sgbj/Dukpt.NET

Comment: Takes a long time to install Visual Studio 2013, but once installed, you can download the zip from GitHub, and open the sln file. Find `Program.cs` in the `Test` project, add `Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit."); Console.ReadKey();` and then hit F5 to Run.

Comment: Here's a boost. Your answer saved my busy week. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[JPos](http://www.jpos.org/) has an implementation of it. But pay attention to the AGPL License, you must not use this code in a commercial application without paying fee

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently uploading to github a project I created for a company a few years ago. If you'd like to check it out, the link is:

https://github.com/otaviokz/DUKPT-Java